# How can build independent dll's that depend on the same source?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am building a few different C# libraries that both depend on a single C# file we'll call `Dep.cs`, and these dll's need to be used together in a Unity project. I'd like to set up these projects in the following way:

1. The C# libraries can be built independently of one another using Visual Studio
2. C# libraries (i.e. dll's) can be imported into a Unity project without conflicting symbols
3. The C# library projects (i.e. the source code for each library via git submodule for example) can be imported into a Unity project without conflicting sources.

I've solved (1) by including `Dep.cs` in each library project that requires it, though this causes issue with (2). And I've solved (3) by putting the dependency in a folder like `Dependencies~` so that Unity ignores the file (this way no duplicate classes are found).

I'm having trouble solving (2) however. I thought I'd be able to add `Dep.cs` as reference in the VS solution but This doesn't seem to work. I've heard of Assembly References but I am not sure if they do what I need.

Comment: Make Dep.cs its own dll and reference it as either a (preferably) project or assembly reference? Project reference means you reference the source code when you compile, and assembly reference means you reference a pre-built dll.

Comment: If you're using Core, you'll have to create a nuget package. Look into .Net Standard Library...your best choice!

Comment: @gunr2171 This would work however I'd prefer to not take ownership of building a dll for source code that I do not mantain. So I am hoping for an alternative solution (if one exists)

Comment: @GHDevOps do NuGet packages get built into the dll? I've looked at alternative dependencies on NuGet but based on how they show up in VS It seemed like their source would be built into my DLL

Comment: @JustinOdle Yep. It will bring any dependency dlls and the project dll into your project.

Comment: @GHDevOps using NuGet is not a great solution for me since it does not work well with Unity. I found a NuGet package for Unity but it doesn't seem to be building the NuGet package properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I decided to modify the external scripts to be internal this way both dll's can compile with that source and not conflict with one another. The rest of the setup in my question remained the same so this solved (2) for me without compromising (1) and (3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Add File as Link" from Visual Studio "Add Existing File" screen. It also works well with git submodule, just place Dep.cs anywhere in a parent folder or in the solution's root directory.

To get the same result you can also directly edit the .csproj file and add a compile instruction:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\..\Path\To\YourFile.cs" Link="YourFile.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This method solves all the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately this still compiles the symbols from `YourFile.cs` into the dll so it does not solve (2)